# filter_extreme in Gensim

Tags: token, gensim, lda

I just started to work with the Gensim module. I applied the filter_extreme to my processed documents.

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs)
print(len(dictionary))
```

the output is `91436`

Then I applied `filter_extreme`,

```
dictionary.filter_extremes(keep_n=None)
print(len(dictionary))
```

the output is `20687`.

From the Gensim documentation, `keep_n=None` will keep all the tokens, however, in my case, the tokens are reduced by 70000. Do I misunderstand the function of `filter_extremes`?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `filter_extremes` [reads](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.corpora.Dictionary.filter_extremes.html):

> `Dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=5, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)`
>
> Filter out tokens that appear in
>
> 1. less than *no_below* documents (absolute number) or
> 2. more than *no_above* documents (fraction of total corpus size, not absolute number).
> 3. after (1) and (2), keep only the first *keep_n* most frequent tokens (or keep all if *None*).
>
> After the pruning, shrink resulting gaps in word ids.
>
> **Note**: Due to the gap shrinking, the same word may have a different word id before and after the call to this function!

As you can see, the method only looks at the `keep_n` value after it discarded tokens based on the values of the first two arguments, `no_below` and `no_above`.

It doesn't seem that you explicitly passed your desired cutoff points for the latter two, so they defaulted to 5 and 0.5, discarding tokens that appear in fewer than five and in more than half of all documents in your corpus, respectively. My guess would be that the latter two criteria were met by roughly 70,000 tokens in your dictionary.

If, for whatever reason, one were to set out to use the `.filter_extremes()` method in a way that guarantees that the dictionary in question remains unchanged, one would need to run it as so: `dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=1, no_above=1, keep_n=None)`.

Note also that gensim's dictionary [comes with another argument](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_extremes) that could cause similar confusion: `prune_at`, with a default value of 2,000,000. If not overridden, it will lead to gensim trying to keep the number of tokens to a maximum of 2,000,000 (and slow your code down quite a bit, given a large enough corpus).